# Trying to call R script from c# application

Tags: c#, r, informix

[Error in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgwv9.jpg) 
[cmd result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vM5u.jpg)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using RDotNet;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Con_R2
{
    class Program
    {
        static string  rPath = "";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SetupPath(); // current process, soon to be deprecated
            using (REngine engine = REngine.CreateInstance("RDotNet"))
            {
                engine.Initialize(); // required since v1.5

                REngine.SetDllDirectory(rPath);

                foreach (string path in engine.Evaluate(".libPaths()").AsCharacter())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(path);
                }
                engine.Evaluate(".libPaths(C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.3.1\\library)");
                engine.Evaluate("source('c:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.1/bin/clustering_loadprofiles.r')");

                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.ReadKey();
            }          
        }

        public static void SetupPath(string Rversion = "R-3.3.1")
        {
            var oldPath = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");
            rPath = System.Environment.Is64BitProcess ?
                                   string.Format(@"C:\Program Files\R\{0}\bin\x64", Rversion) :
                                   string.Format(@"C:\Program Files\R\{0}\bin\i386", Rversion);

            if (!Directory.Exists(rPath))
                throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(
                  string.Format(" R.dll not found in : {0}", rPath));
            var newPath = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", rPath,
                                         System.IO.Path.PathSeparator, oldPath);
            System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", newPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Getting this error

> Error in sqlFetch(channel, "sysadmin.loadprofile_allcustomers") :
>   first argument is not an open RODBC channel In addition: Warning
>   messages: 1: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=informix116") :
>   [RODBC] ERROR: state IM014, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver
>   Manager] he specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between
>   the Driver and Appl ation 2: In
>   RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=informix116") : ODBC connection failed

Comment: The code you show and the error you've listed dont really help.. as you arent controlling the odbc from that code.. you have a mismatch of slash types between libpaths and source.. which line produces the error? what is the actual output of your app

Comment: @BugFinder :  Have attached the error screenshots

Comment: Well the obvious issue goes back to the slashes... windows doesnt do forwards slashes....

Comment: @BugFinder : The same code is running when I am trying to print  "Hello" from the file , but while connecting through database using dsn it is giving error

Comment: it would seem then your connection string is wrong

Comment: @BugFinder : when i try to run the same script using command prompt it executes properly without any error , but when I try to run it through code gives error. The DSN part is wriiten inside the R file and not in the code

Comment: Check if you are not getting a conflict between 32 and 64 bits ODBC Data Sources.

Comment: thanks done ... after installing informix 32 bit odbc driver it worked for me .

Comment: As @LuísMarques said conflict between 32 and 64 bits ODBC